# Improve Swift loop performance

Tags: ios, swift, performance, loops

I am writing a nested loop in swift.

I am creating some simple loops using ranges:

```
for i in 0..<someCount {
   for j in 0..<someOtherCount {
       //some logic here, or even just keep it empty
   }
}
```

My function is called a few times in my program. If you multiple someCount and someOtherCount, it maxes out at around 2097152 elements, so its not trivial, but definitely shouldn't be causing performance issues.

The problem I am having is that it runs great in Release builds, but debug builds are so slow it's unbelievable. I spend minutes waiting in this loop, even if I remove the body so it not doing anything. I looked at it in the profiler (Instruments) a few days ago. I can't remember exactly the part that was taking all the time, but I remember it ended in .next() - so its probably IteratorProtocol.next() or something.

I am wondering if anyone knows any shortcuts/workarounds/alternative syntax I can use to reduce the overhead in debug builds. Maybe an alternative looping API that has reasonable performance?

Or perhaps this is a known issue with swift and there is not much I can do for now or than raise a discussion/bug with the swift project?

My program takes 55 seconds if I comment out those loops and if I add those empty loops back in - it jumps to 100 seconds.

Comment: I never said I was running it on the main thread, I am running it on a background thread. Anyway I'm not really sure how that is relevant.

I guess I should have made it clearer that the release build actually has processing inside the loop, and that section of the code is still faster than the debug build with nothing in it. But I guess that isnt really the issue. The issue is that just declaring the loops slows the execution of my program to unusable levels.

For now I switched to a "while loop" so I can still develop my program (well I created a function to convert it to a while loop).

Comment: I am doing some processing on a matrix of data. 2m elements isn't really that much though, if I wrote this in c or Sharp it would run plenty fast.

Comment: @RufusMall Swift is pretty much the same speed at C# really, no big difference

Comment: In this specific scenario @aheze? I would be quite surprised. I have done Csharp dev in the past  mplementing similar stuff and never had problems where simple loops would slow me down in debug builds.

Edit: I just tested it, wrote a simple nested loop, summing data and printing it out at the end in Csharp debug builds, the loops bare take any time at all when compared to the swift version. Not sure where you were getting your information from.

Comment: @RufusMall [you were saying..?](https://github.com/aheze/DeveloperAssets/issues/4#issuecomment-830661886) 2,250,000 elements, 0.239567791 seconds.

Comment: @aheze Exactly!! Thanks for writing an example to replicate it. 0.24 is huge for such a small loop. I have a work around for now. I hope swift resolve the issue in the future!

Comment: @RufusMall hmm ok... 0.24 sounds like a tiny amount to me though ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: It depends what you are doing. Remember this may be called multiple times and you haven't actually put any logic in the loop yet.

This wastefulness adds up. By changing my loops the processing now takes NINE seconds instead of ranging between 45-60 seconds. When iterating on a feature that is a HUGE deal. Anyway, thanks for trying to help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For now I wrote a function to loop that I can use instead (lol). I left a "for i in..." implementation here incase someone else wants to try it out for themselves.

Switching all the loops has improved the processing of my processing pipeline for small data sets:
From: 45.642573105025804 - 60 seconds
To: always executing in about 9 seconds.

For larger datasets this is obviously even more impactful.

```
func loop(iterations: Int, body: (Int) -> Void) {
    var i = 0
//    for i in 0..<iterations {
//        body(i)
//    }
    while i < iterations {
        body(i)
        i += 1
    }
}
```

TLDR: if you are writing nested for loops for something critical, such as for ML or image processing/matrix math or some game development- you can probably improve performance in debug builds by switching to while loops.

Comment: Might be worth filing a bug with Apple. Maybe they can improve the iterator here.

Comment: Thank you!  The super slow for loop was driving me crazy.   Knowing the while-loop workaround and that RELEASE builds seem to be very fast, I'm doing better now.